# Machine Learning: Getting error in Confusion Matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, random-forest, confusion-matrix

While running random forest regression model, I am getting error while running the confusion matrix. The model is able to predict the y_pred but I am not able to check the accuracy since I am not able to run accuracy matrix.

Datatypes:

```
type(y_test)
Out[124]: numpy.ndarray

type(y_pred)
Out[125]: numpy.ndarray
```

Below is my code for confusion matrix:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

print(matrix)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Error:

```
confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-121-7a3dbcfd18a0>", line 1, in <module>
confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

File "/Users/srikantswamy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn  /metrics/classification.py", line 253, in confusion_matrix
y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)

File "/Users/srikantswamy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn /metrics/classification.py", line 88, in _check_targets
raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))

ValueError: continuous is not supported
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a simple answer : A confusion matrix is a table that is often used to **describe the performance of a classification model (or "classifier")** . In your case you are trying to find the confusion matrix for the continuous variables. for regression use mean square error.
Have a look at this lecture pdf: http://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/sml/lectures/lecture3_handout.pdf

Comment: Thanks, yes my output was in float.

Answer (score 1):

The main problems solved by supervised learning are Regression and Classification. There are different ways of telling them apart, but basically if your output is continuous, say you input a vector and expect a real number as an output, you're facing a Regression problem, whereas if your output consist of classes (discrete output), say you input a vector and expect a yes or no, a digit from 0 to 9, a kind of animal, etc. you're facing a Classification problem.

In classification problems you can use metrics like accuracy, misclassification, cross-entropy, f1-score, etc. because they rely on checking whether or not inputs were predicted in the correct class, but there's no way to do this in regression problems, just try to imagine a confusion matrix with infinite classes. In regression, common metrics are, for instance, mean square error and mean absolute error.

In conclusion:

- If you're facing a classification problem you should switch to another model, like Random Forest Clasifier.
- If you're facing a regression problem you should switch to another metric, like  mean square error. A useful visualization using this metric could be a histogram of the errors.

Comment: Thanks this really helped. Yes my prediction output was float numbers.